# Need to refresh page after each change

Tags: cache

When I'm trying to activate theme in WP I can't see that it was activated, but see old theme is still activated. Then I want to see how it look like and need refresh page again to see new theme represent in main page.
How to avoid regular need to refresh pages in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding to .htaccess

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```